# How can i scrape values from a JSON in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing, scrape

i'm looking to parse this multiple values and assign them to a unique variable for each thread that i'm running.

```
{
"products": [
    {
        "PID1": [
            {
                "stock":0,
                "status": "unavailable"
            }
        ],
        "PID2": [
            {
                "stock":0,
                "status": "unavailable"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely for each thread that i'm running i should get the PID, eg. Thread 1 needs to scrape PID1, Thread 2 = PID2 and so on